# How to remove spaces from a query string using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, query-string, querystringparameter

Iam using query sting in jquery

to get URL values iam using

```
    function getUrlVars() {
var vars = [], hash;
var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    vars.push(hash[0]);
    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
}
return vars;
```

Here when i pass Query String to URL it is giving spaces as %20 and when i fectch value from URL iam getting vaue of name as Name%20Name format

What should i do in order to get name with space as seperation??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `decodeURIComponent()` Javascript function:

```
decodeURIComponent("Name%20Name") // "Name Name"
```

> Decodes a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) component previously created by encodeURIComponent or by a similar routine.

For more information see [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

Answer (score 1):

Use the native Javascript function [unescape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.unescape), it is supported in all major browsers:

```
var a = "Name%20Name";
window.unescape(a);
```

Comment: But here when i pass a to my Json calls Data iam not getting my [WebMethod] hitting.., taugh its a string

Answer (score 0):

You can turn any encoded urls to "normal" representation using `decodeURIComponent();`

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(decodeURIComponent(hash[0]));
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```